# Converting point to polygon in a given distance

Tags: qgis, point, multipoint

I'm working in QGIS 2.18 but I can work with QGIS 3 or ArcMap 10.2.

I have a multipoint layer providing from a lasDataset where I've isolated the buildings.

I want to create a polygon layer where every building or group of buildings are individual polygons. The problem is I can't use any attribute to group them because I don't have any. Concave Hull only creates one polygon. So I have to group them by other way. by distance? How can I do it?

The points I have
[image: The points I have]

How I want to group them
[image: How I want to group them]

Comment: Do the points have any attributes which define the groups?

Comment: I suggest you to look at [DBSCAN clustering](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#dbscan-clustering) tool in QGIS 3. It produces `CLUSTER_ID` attribute.

Comment: I can't use any attribute to group them because I don't have any.

Answer (score 2):

A super simple solution: buffer your points by your desired distance, with a dissolve.  Then, inward buffer by that same distance (use a negative distance value). Since the initial buffers were dissolved, the area between points will not be removed by inward buffering and will create those polygons for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution but only if you have the original LAS file, so it works for me. But I'll be happy to know if there is other way to proceed if you have the multipoint shape.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lastools/JBHef3TANI4